# Display categories that only contain images

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I developed a gallery of images separated by several categories.

I just want to display categories that contain images.

I have three categories: "new", "old", "try".

Of these three categories, only new and old have images. My problem is that all categories are appearing, even those that have no image (as is the case with try).

Is there a way to present only the categories that contain images?

How can I do this?

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hf69m9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**code**

```
<div *ngFor="let cat of Cats">
  <div class="row ">
    <span class="">{{cat}}</span>
  </div>
  <ul class="mdc-image-list my-image-list" style="padding-left: 10px;padding-right: 10px;">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let product of data; let  j = index;">
      <li class="mdc-image-list__item" *ngIf="product.Cat == cat">
        <div class="mdc-image-list__image-aspect-container">
          <ng-container *ngIf="product.image == null; else productImage">
            <img src="./assets/image-not-found.svg" class="mdc-image-list__image imagenotfound">
          </ng-container>
          <ng-template #productImage>
            <img [src]="product.image" class="mdc-image-list__image">
          </ng-template>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ng-container>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

The try should not be presented :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your category div in an `<ng-container>`, and then use `*ngIf` to check if your data array contains a product in a given category. The best way to achieve that is to have an array with product counts per given category.

Add this to your AppComponent class:

```js
  get counts() {
    return this.data.reduce((obj, value) => {
      if (value.Cat in obj) {
        obj[value.Cat]++;
      } else {
        obj[value.Cat] = 1;
      }

      return obj;
    }, {});
  }
```

And then use this as your template:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let cat of Cats">
  <div *ngIf="counts[cat]">
    <div class="row ">
      <span class="">{{cat}}</span>
    </div>
    <ul class="mdc-image-list my-image-list" style="padding-left: 10px;padding-right: 10px;">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let product of data; let  j = index;">
        <li class="mdc-image-list__item" *ngIf="product.Cat == cat">
          <div class="mdc-image-list__image-aspect-container">
            <ng-container *ngIf="product.image == null; else productImage">
              <img src="./assets/image-not-found.svg" class="mdc-image-list__image imagenotfound">
            </ng-container>
            <ng-template #productImage>
              <img [src]="product.image" class="mdc-image-list__image">
            </ng-template>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ng-container>
    </ul>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks for your tip and also for trying to help me! Your solution has an error: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined ("<ng-container * ngFor =" let cat of Cats ">
<div [ERROR ->] * ngIf = "data.find ((product) => product.Cat == cat)">

Comment: I've updated it once again to contain the computed count array instead. Which should be much better optimized.

Answer (score 1):

You can write format function, write data as an object where the key is category, value is array of images and use `keyvalue` pipe.

For example:

component property: `formattedData: {[key: string]: string[]} = {}`

format function:

```
formatData(data: {image: string; cat: string}[]): void {
        data.forEach((item: {image: string; cat: string}) => {
        if (this.formattedData[item.cat]) {
          this.formattedData[item.cat].push(item.image)
        } else {
          this.formattedData[item.cat] = [item.image]
        }
      });
}
```

call the format function in constructor:

```
constructor() {
  this.formatData(this.data);
}
```

template:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of formattedData | keyvalue">
  <div class="row">
    <span class="">{{item.key}}</span>
  </div>
  <ul class="mdc-image-list my-image-list" style="padding-left: 10px;padding-right: 10px;">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let image of item.value;">
      <li class="mdc-image-list__item">
        <div class="mdc-image-list__image-aspect-container">
            <img [src]="image ? image : './assets/image-not-found.svg'" class="mdc-image-list__image" [ngClass]="{'imagenotfound': !image}">
        </div>
      </li>
    </ng-container>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I think it looks better because we have a little less logic in the template. You have only listed categories that have images.